# Can't create a Store package (Version Identity must be greater than...)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to create a package for a new update of my app, but I can't get it done.

I always used to just right click on my project, then Store > Create package, select the target (Release, ARM), set the version number and the click create, and everything worked fine.

Now I'm getting an error:

> The Version attribute of the Identity element in the application manifest must be greater than 2015.619.940.885

That number is the package version of the last update I published (on June, 19 as you can see from the number itself).

The point is that I always put my own version number in Visual Studio and inside the manifest (like 1.3.0.0 for example) and then VS automatically created its own package number (like 2015.619.940.885) for the generated package.

Right now instead it looks like VS wants me to manually set a number like that in the app version, and that makes no sense.

I don't know why it just started doing that right now, it has always worked fine.
I mean, am I doing something wrong here? What should I do to fix this thing?

I really don't know what to do, and I won't be able to publish my update until I get this thing fixed.

Thank you so much for your help,

Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not the only one, this happens because your account got migrated to the new dev center dashboard. You can't use versions like "1.x.y", now you need to use the date format. You can show a user friendly version in the description of the app, or inside the app(maybe in a settings page, or about, etc) if it's very important.

You can find more info here:
http://adamkinney.com/blog/2015/07/03/windows-phone-8-1-store-package-version-change-surprise-one-act/

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! If I really got migrated to the new one though, why do I still see the old one? I mean, I keep using the old dev center without problems, and I didn't get any email/notification about the switch

Comment: Microsoft will automatically migrate you and will notify you via the contact email in your account dashboard once your migration is complete. The migration started a few weeks ago I think, but I think this is a "feature", not an issue from them. You can find out more about this here:
http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/dev-center-account-migration-begins-next-week/